# Remapped Caps Lock to Control works except for with Control-C (/interrupt)

Tags: keyboard

The left `control` key on my external keyboard seems not to be working and so I remapped the `Caps Lock` to `control`;

[image]

Hitting `Caps Lock-A` results in `Ctl-A`:

[image]

But hitting `Caps Lock-C` results in `c`:

[image]

While I realize this is a fairly obscure/corner case situation I still wanted to see if anyone had an idea on it.   I am on Mojave and using iterm2.

Comment: Which macOS version are you running? Which is your shell?

Comment: updated OP with those versions